# Regex text to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a text file that contains multiple lines in the format given below:

```
real    0m0.020s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
Round  1  completed. with matrix size of  1200 x 1200 with threads 8

real    0m0.022s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.001s
Round  2  completed. with matrix size of  1200 x 1200 with threads 8
```

There are about 500 entries of the this sort(above is an example of 2). I can't seem to figure out how to get them into a pandas dataframe that might look something like this:

```
Matrix Size    Threads    Round    Real    User    Sys
1200 x 1200    8          1        0.0020  0.0000  0.0000
1200 x 1200    8          2        0.0022  0.0000  0.0001
```

Is there a way using regex or some other way to convert the test output into a dataframe. Additionally I don't know if I interpreted the times correctly either as they are in 0m(I think 0 minutes) and the 0.02 (I think 0.02 seconds)

Comment: Are there always two newlines between blocks that will each form a row of the dataframe?

Comment: I bet the time you ask this question and wait for answer is enough for you to create and run a simple for loop solution on that 500 entries :-)

Comment: Yeah, each block will forma a record and there are two new lines between them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

regex = re.compile(r'real +(\dm\d\.\d+s)\nuser +(\dm\d\.\d+s)\nsys +(\dm\d\.\d+s)\nRound +(\d+).+of +(\d+ x \d+).+threads (\d+)')

df = pd.DataFrame(regex.findall(data), columns=['real', 'user', 'sys', 'round', 'matrix size', 'threads'])

print(df)
```

Output:

```
       real      user       sys round  matrix size threads
0  0m0.020s  0m0.000s  0m0.000s     1  1200 x 1200       8
1  0m0.022s  0m0.000s  0m0.001s     2  1200 x 1200       8
```

Comment: Is there a way i could convert the 0m0.020s to (0*60)[from the m] + (0.020)[from the s]

Comment: @user9996043 How about `df['real'].str.replace('s', '').str.split('m').map(lambda t: float(t[0]) * 60 + float(t[1]))`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to solve the problem using only `pandas` you can use `str.split()`:

```
# data
s = """real    0m0.020s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
Round  1  completed. with matrix size of  1200 x 1200 with threads 8

real    0m0.022s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.001s
Round  2  completed. with matrix size of  1200 x 1200 with threads 8"""

# str.split on two line breaks for rows then split on the text
df = pd.DataFrame(s.split('\n\n'))[0].str.split('   |real | with |user    |sys |matrix size of  |threads |\n')\
                                  .apply(lambda x: [s for s in x if s]).apply(pd.Series)

# split col 3 on round and completed to get number of rounds
df[3] = df[3].str.strip('Round | completed.')

# rename columns
df.columns = ['real', 'user', 'sys', 'round', 'matrix size', 'threads']
```

out

```
       real      user       sys round  matrix size threads
0  0m0.020s  0m0.000s  0m0.000s     1  1200 x 1200       8
1  0m0.022s  0m0.000s  0m0.001s     2  1200 x 1200       8
```

note that it will be slower gmds' example:

`1000 loops, best of 3: 4.42 ms per loop` vs `1000 loops, best of 3: 1.84 ms per loop`